# Calculating Median of a column for rows where 2 other columns match criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

Unfortunately, excel doesn't allow for median calculation in pivot tables so I am trying to do something similar with a formula.

For my example, I have 5 columns of data (A-E).

My columns A & B have different data classifying variables. Column E has the data for which I need the median. 
However, I want to be filtering to certain values from A & B to calculate the median for the rows with those filtered values only (like I would in a pivot)

Anyone know the best formula that by saying when A=x and when B=y, calculate the Median of column E. So only for the rows that A=x and B=y holds true. I have tried a few IF formulas but they don't seem to give the correct response.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[From the help files for MEDIAN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MEDIAN-function-d0916313-4753-414c-8537-ce85bdd967d2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), we see that "If an array or reference argument contains text, logical values, or empty cells, those values are ignored; however, cells with the value zero are included." So one solution would be (let's say in column F) to set an IF formula that returns the value in column E if the criteria are met, and `""` or similar if the criteria are not met. Then just take the median of column F.

Suppose I want to know the median cuteness only of brown-eyed dogs:

[image: Median only of cells meeting criteria]

Which gives the required result:

[image: Excel results for MEDIAN only of cells meeting criteria]

This is not a brilliant solution, but it's a workable one. You get to see very explicitly which cells have been selected, so you can see immediately if you've used the right `IF`, but the downside is you might prefer not to have a column used in this way.

The "smarter" method is to use an array formula, but this doesn't give you such a visual check on which cells you selected:

```
=MEDIAN(IF((A2:A9="Dog")*(B2:B9="Brown"),E2:E9,""))
```

Remember to press CONTROL-SHIFT-ENTER to finish entering the array formula; the enter key alone is not enough. The `IF` in the array formula effectively selects only those cells in E2:E9 that match the criteria, and the `MEDIAN` will then only apply to the cells you want. This means you can then do something like this to get a table of medians according to various criteria:

[image: Table of Excel medians according to different criteria]

Take care with the absolute and relative cell references to make it easier to drag the formula! For instance the array formula in `H2` should be as follows; note that in `H$1` the row is fixed but the column will vary as you drag, and the reverse for `$G2`.

```
=MEDIAN(IF(($A$2:$A$9=H$1)*($B$2:$B$9=$G2),$E$2:$E$9,""))
```

This gives a handy table of results.

[image]